# Conditional Formatting in VBA Macro not working in excel 2007

Tags: excel, vba

Expert please help. The following VBA code does work in excel 2010 but not in 2007. 
It displays error "application or object undefined". It seems that "selection.FormatConditions.Font" is not supported.

```
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
    Formula1:="=""BREAK TOP"""
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Color = -16752384  --- Error: application and object undefined 
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: This [is supported in Excel 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb223827(v=office.12).aspx) according to the Dev reference. I test the code in 2010 and it is working. In any case, if the `.Font` was a problem, the error would occur on the `With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font` line, not the `.Color` statement.

Comment: @DavidZemens Thanks! If comment out ".Color" and ".TintAndShade", the program can run without error. I updated the compatibility pack from Microsoft already but still it doesn't help. Kindly advice!

Comment: I think you need to use an `RGB` color assignment in 2007. This does not work with negative color values. I will post a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to test this in 2007 Excel, but the error is definitely not with the `FormatConditions.Font` object.  The error raises in your assginment of the `.Font.Color`.

Reviewing the dev reference for the `.Font` object in 2007, it seems that you should use an `RGB()` formula to assign the color.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb213182(v=office.12).aspx

However, my Google-Fu indicates that you *cannot* use a negative color value with an `RBG` assignment. You will need to choose a different color, I think.  There are some ways around this using WinAPI perhaps, but I am not able to test that approach at the moment.

I chose another blue which is similar in hue to your `-16752384`.

```
Sub test()

'## This section converts a long color to its R/G/B components
    Dim col As Long: col = 15773696
    Dim r As Long, g As Long, b As Long
    r = col Mod 256
    g = (col \ 256) Mod 256
    b = (col \ 256 \ 256) Mod 256

'## Your code, with modification for the RGB Formula:
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
        Formula1:="=""BREAK TOP"""
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = RGB(r, g, b) '<-- RGB Formula, here.
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With


End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

Try this, do not use `Selection` object.

```
Sub test2()

Dim rng as Range
Dim fc as FormatCondition
Set rng = Range(Selection.Address)

'## This section converts a long color to its R/G/B components
    Dim col As Long: col = 15773696
    Dim r As Long, g As Long, b As Long
    r = col Mod 256
    g = (col \ 256) Mod 256
    b = (col \ 256 \ 256) Mod 256

'## Your code, with modification for the RGB Formula:
    rng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
        Formula1:="=""BREAK TOP"""
    rng.FormatConditions(rng.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

    Set fc = rng.FormatConditions(1)
    fc.Font.Color = RGB(r, g, b) '<-- RGB Formula, here.
    fc.Font.TintAndShade = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! However I still got the same error. I tried tested it by putting ".Color = 3", but "error 1004: Application and object undefined" still appeared. Please help!

Comment: If you put `.Color = 3` then you did **not** try what I suggested. Try again. Copy my code exactly, and run it. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi David I tried both your code and mine. Both stops at the same place and displayed the same error. Thanks much!!

Comment: The only other suggestion I could offer is to rewrite your code to avoid using `Selection`. It's a clumsy method that sometimes has problems.  Then, use the Locals window to debug.

Comment: Thanks so much! I just tried, the same error appeared...really strange, I tested them on excel 2010 are all okay, but all stopped at the same ".Color" statement with the same error. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Nope :(  I wish I could test this but I only have 2010 and an old laptop with 2003, so unfortunately I can't get in there and test it in the 2007 environment.